# Extending the group ID extractor in WSO2 APIM for Custom User Claim

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am trying to use custom group Ids for Application user mapping in WSO2 APIM. I am following this WSO2 documentation -> [WSO2-Sharing-Applications](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/consume/manage-application/sharing-applications/sharing-applications/#extending-the-group-id-extractor)

I see, we have to extend "NewPostLoginExecutor" and override the following method ->

```
String[] getGroupingIdentifierList(String response);
```

I don't see much of an information related to maven dependency in the documentation, if any one has used it, can you provide more information on how to use it ??

Also, the same URI also contains a section for "Defining a custom user claim as the group extractor claim URI", more information on how to use it will also be helpful ???

Answer (score 0):

You should use the dependencies based on the APIM version. You can find the versions of the different maven dependencies from the product repo. For example, apim 4.1.0 relevant dependencies can be found in here (https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v4.1.0/pom.xml).

Similarly you can find dependencies by going through the tags.